# How do I print the values of the HKQuantity type I just recorded and saved to Healthkit store?

Tags: swift, healthkit, watchos, heartbeat

I am sharing a workout to the HKStore and I have requested the following types tot read:

```
let typesToRead: Set = [
    HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!,
    HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)!,
    HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning)!
]
```

In my workout session class (that tracks and records an active workout) I am able to record live data and save it to HealthStore but **I don't know how to read that data and display it on screen for the users to view live during there workout.** (or at least print the heart rate, activeEnergyBurned etc data in console).

Here is the HKLiveWorkoutBuilderDelegate that seems to be sharing the relevant workout data

```
// MARK: HKLiveWorkoutBuilderDelegate
func workoutBuilder(_ workoutBuilder: HKLiveWorkoutBuilder, didCollectDataOf collectedTypes: Set<HKSampleType>) {
    for type in collectedTypes {
        guard let quantityType = type as? HKQuantityType else {
            return // Nothing to do
        }

        let statistics = workoutBuilder.statistics(for: quantityType)
        let typeDescription = type.description

    }
}
```

And here is how my workout is activated:

```
    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        configuration.activityType = .running
        configuration.locationType = .indoor

        do {
            session = try HKWorkoutSession(healthStore: healthStore, configuration: configuration)
            builder = session.associatedWorkoutBuilder()
        } catch {
            dismiss()
            return
        }

        // Setup session and builder
        session.delegate = self
        builder.delegate = self
        builder.dataSource = HKLiveWorkoutDataSource(healthStore: healthStore, workoutConfiguration: configuration)


        // Start session and builder
        session.startActivity(with: Date())
        builder.beginCollection(withStart: Date()) { (success, error) in
            self.setDurationTimerDate()
        }
    }
```

**Note: I am using Apples new Beta WatchOS 5.0**

Answer (score 8):

You are doing most of the things, but you need to also enable the collecting of data to the `dataSource`. In my app I collect distance and heart rate data, I do it like this:

```
let dataSource = HKLiveWorkoutDataSource(healthStore: healthStore, workoutConfiguration: configuration)

if let hr = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate) {
    dataSource.enableCollection(for: hr, predicate: nil)
}
if let distance = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning) {
    dataSource.enableCollection(for: distance, predicate: nil)
}

workoutBuilder?.dataSource = dataSource
```

Then I can print that information in the `HKLiveWorkoutBuilderDelegate` method like this:

```
func workoutBuilder(_ workoutBuilder: HKLiveWorkoutBuilder, didCollectDataOf collectedTypes: Set<HKSampleType>) {

    guard let hrType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate),
        let distanceType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning) else {
            return
    }

    if collectedTypes.contains(hrType) {
        if let hrQuantity = workoutBuilder.statistics(for: hrType)?.mostRecentQuantity() {
            // We want to have BPM
            let hrUnit = HKUnit(from: "count/min")
            let hr = Int(hrQuantity.doubleValue(for: hrUnit))

            debugPrint("HR: \(hr)")
        }
    }

    if collectedTypes.contains(distanceType) {
        if let distQuantity = workoutBuilder.statistics(for: distanceType)?.sumQuantity() {
            // We want to have total distance in meters
            let distance = distQuantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.meter())

            debugPrint("Distance: \(distance) m")
        }
    }
}
```

And then I get in console:

```
"Distance: 6.5 m"
"Distance: 10.4 m"
"HR: 112"
"Distance: 14.3 m"
"HR: 117"
"Distance: 20.8 m"
```